# What traits does a man have, when he is apt to feeling threatened by strong women?

Tags: social-psychology, abnormal-psychology, sexuality

This isn't intended as a gender biased question, as both men and women can have strange hang ups when it comes to either sex.

I am curious about men who are threatened by strong women. By strong women, I mean intelligent, capable, financially independent, self assured and assertive.

By threatened I mean unduly intimidated, nervous or uneasy, which can result in a number of reactions.

What personality traits, background or pathology do men who are threatened by this type of woman, generally,  have in common?

Are there any studies on this?

Comment: A person of substance accepts everyone with
Respect, an open-mind, and heart...Gender is not a factor!

Comment: I think it's really important to know if the type of woman you are defining is also physically attractive. If she is, then such woman can be perceived as being "way out of one's league", thus eliciting a response similar to crossing a narrow bridge very high up - there's too much attention being paid to "not screwing it up", which disrupts normal thinking patterns